# How to end my while loop?

Tags: c++

Hey can anyone lend me a hand? How can I make my loop end after the first calculation? After i complete one calculation such as addition, I would like to end it. Sorry for the noobie questions. I'm just learning loops now in my class. Greatly appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int numOne;
    int numTwo;
    int result;
    string operation;

    cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
    cin >> operation;
    while (operation == "e" || operation == "E")
    {
        cout << "Operation type invalid." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
        cin >> operation;
    }

    while (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "*" || operation == "/")
    {
        cout << "Please enter integer one: ";
        cin >> numOne;
        cout << "Please enter integer two: ";
        cin >> numTwo;

    if (operation == "+")
    {
        result = numOne + numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << "." << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
    }
    else if (operation == "-")
    {
        result = numOne - numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << "." << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
    }
    else if (operation == "*")
    {
        result = numOne * numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
    }
    else if (operation == "/")
    {
        if (numTwo == 0)
        {
                cout << "You cannot divide by zero!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
        result = numOne / numTwo;
        cout << "The numbers you entered were " << numOne << "," << numTwo << endl;
        cout << "The operation you chose was " << operation << "." << endl;
        cout << "The operations result is " << result << endl;
        cout << "Your equation was: " << numOne << " " << operation << " " << numTwo << " = " << result << ".";
        }
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I'm not allowed to use `break`. Is there another way?

Comment: Have you tried "Break"?

Comment: It's really worth looking at building a simple parser here rather than this contraption to process data.

Comment: you dont need all that code to understand how a while loop works....

Comment: _@Jeff_ For starters: Appropriate indentation of your code will help a lot to identify the problem.

Comment: _@Jeff_ Please add all of that silly restrictions/requirements (_"I can't use `break`"_, _"I can't use `do { ] while()`"_, etc.) to your question. The way it is it's not very productive or helpful for future research.

Answer (score 3):

You can end a while loop using...

```
break;
```

ie

```
if(!(operation == "e" || operation == "E")) {
  break;
}
```

Normally to end a `while` loop the `(EXPRESSION)` in the following ie

```
while((EXPRESSION) == true) { execute_code_here();}
```

needs to evaluate to false. The expression can be made up of many logical pieces ie

```
while (a == b && c != d && f++ < 1000) {do_something_here();}
```

The `break` keyword is used to terminate a while loop early but this can also be achieved by adding something to the expression that allows you to terminate the while loop ie make the expression evaluate to false, this is normally done using a flag or a counter.

To achieve the same effect as `break` without using it you can use this technique with `continue`. You then use the flag or counter along with `continue` to achieve the same thing as break ie, this is a counter example

```
while(a == b && flag++ < 1000) {
  if(this_returns_true()) {
    flag = 10000;
    continue;
  }
  /*The code here may not be executed*/
}
```

Using a boolean flag it would be...

```
while(a == b && flag == true) {
  if(this_returns_true()) {
    flag = false;
    continue;
  }
  /*The code here may not be executed*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `break;` with an `if` statement inside the while loop.
 So that if a condition is `true` you will break out from the while loop.

Example

```
if (operation != "e")
    break;
```

If you're not allowed to use `break`, I suggest you don't use a loop. And just calculate it once.

Comment: Or he could construct his loop condition so it would be `false` on the condition where he wants to exit the loop. He *could* also use `goto` although that would be *really* bad style.

Answer (score 1):

Just change the `while` to `if`. There's no need for a loop if you only want to execute something once.

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced with C++ but I think you mean the `break;` statement

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/37zc9d2w.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
break;
```

This will end the loop each time. You can wrap an if statement around it to apply conditions for exiting.

Comment: I'm not allowed to use break;. Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

The code block:

> ```
> cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
> cin >> operation;
> while (operation == "e" || operation == "E")
> {
>     cout << "Operation type invalid." << endl;
>     cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
>     cin >> operation;
> }
> ```

Doesn't do what you're promising the user:

```
Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program:
```

If `"e"` or `"E"` is entered, the loop won't stop and ask for input again.

You probably want to have something like this:

```
do {
    cin >> operation;
    while (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "*" || operation == "/") {
        // ...
   }
} while(operation != "e" && operation != "E");
```

---

As for your silly restrictions not to use `do {} while();` (kick your professor in the ass, do twice at least):

```
cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
cin >> operation;
while(operation != "e" && operation != "E") {
    if (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "*" || operation == "/") {
        // ...
    }
    else {
        cout << "Operation type invalid." << endl;
        cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
        cin >> operation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that would be a do while loop, wouldn't it? I can't have that in my program. I'm stuck strictly to completing my program with a sentinel loop.

Comment: @JeffMann Sure. Any problems with that?

Answer (score 0):

If you have to use the while loop just add break; and that will break out of the loop. If you don't have to I would change that to an if statement. Example: if(varName == '+'){

Num1 + num2;}

Sorry for format, on mobile

Answer (score 0):

I guess that what you are actually trying to achieve is this.
The first loop should be refactored (ie: loop until operation is nether 'e' nor 'E'), the second loop should be an if-else-statement (checking whether the operation is valid).

```
int main()
{
    int numOne;
    int numTwo;
    int result;
    string operation;

    cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
    cin >> operation;
    while (operation != "e" && operation != "E") {

        if (operation == "+" || operation == "-" || operation == "*" || operation == "/") {
             // your valid operation code...
        } else {
            cout << "Operation type invalid." << endl;
        }

        cout << "Please enter what operation you'd like to perform or e/E to end program: ";
        cin >> operation;
    }

    return 0;
}
```